# Where does the global packages get installed and how do they get executed in Python as well as Node?

Tags: python, node.js, npm, pip

I want to debug some globally installed packages, both in Python as well as Node. I checked my environment variables in windows as well as on ubuntu, but 
could not find them declared in the environment variables.
Firstly, how do I find their locations.
Secondly, how do I know which file is executed when I call some globally declared package. e.g:
For Node:

```
grunt someFile.js
```

For Python:

```
syntribos someFiles.conf
```

Comment: If you are using nvm then this is the path `/home/arpit/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules`. Browse acccordingly on your system

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages

Answer (score 1):

I have found some answer for Python:
First check where the global packages are installed:
**Command:**

```
python -m site --user-site
```

**Output:**

```
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Go to this directory and find the package you are looking for.
Thereafter, we can use:
    `pip show -f package_name`
This will show us some thing as follows:

```
Entry-points:
  [console_scripts]
  syntribos = syntribos.runner:entry_point
  [oslo.config.opts]
  syntribos.config = syntribos.config:list_opts
```

Then from here on, we can start debugging our scripts?
e.g:  **[console_scripts]** will be the entry point for the package.

Is it fine? or is there more to it?
And I am still looking for Node.