# Install webpack offline

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have a linux machine where I don't have external internet connection. I have to be able to generate a build for a react-js app using the webpack utilitary. I dont't have access to the internet so I have copied the node modules manually. In the directory node-modules I have the webpack module but I am unable to run the webpack command.

Comment: Have you tried `npm rebuild`? This will recompile the binaries. If they where build on a different machine they often don't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the `webpack` command, or any other command from the terminal for that matter, the module has to be installed globally.

Alternatively, you can run the command by accessing the library directory:

```
./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js <optional_extra_args_here>
```

If this doesn't work also please specify what "I am unable to run the webpack command" means

Answer (score 0):

Running the script manually is a viable solution, but I was able to have a good result after...

- Copying the files from the `node_modules` and paste it to `C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` as that will make it work globally. And
- Going to the directory of individual, buggy dependencies, like webpack-cli, and running `npm pack` after setting the `bundleDependencies` to true, as shown below.

```json
{
  //...

  "bundleDependencies": true
}
```

As you use a Linux machine, the directory above won't work for you as that is for Windows systems. That is the directory where all global dependencies are installed in, so after a simple research on Linux systems, I found that...

- Unix systems place the global dependencies on `/usr/local/lib/node` or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` and there is where you should paste your newly copied dependencies. ([Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages))

**Note:** I, sometimes, was still having troubles after copying the node_modules because I haven't run `npm rebuild` on the project's directory. So, try that if nothing worked.

Wish that helps!