# create-react-app error - Cannot find module 'fs-extra'

Tags: create-react-app, fs-extra

When I run `create-react-app` in the CLI I get the following error message back:

```
    $ create-react-app udacity-goals-todo
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fs-extra'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js:40:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling `create-react-app` as well as reinstalling `fs-extra`.

Any ideas on how to get this up and running again?

Comment: What happens when you do `npx create-react-app udacity-goals-todo`?

Comment: Can't believe I forgot the npx....thanks.

Comment: did that fix it?

Answer (score 4):

you can fix this by uninstalling create-react-app and re-installing it

- For mac users

1) right-click finder desktop widget

2) click "go to folder"

3) type " /usr/local/lib/node_modules " then enter

4) delete create-react-app folder

5) in terminal type in " npm i -g create-react-app "

- for window users, i dont know where the globals folder is sorry. i will update this when i find it

Comment: It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue earlier with the create-react-app and 'tar' module. I did the following steps to fix it:

```
npm cache clear --force

npm i
npm i -g create-react-app
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. Although I've always run create-react-app using npx.

The issue was solved by cleaning the yarn cache, `yarn cache clean`

Answer (score 1):

Facing same or similar issue when running the following:

```
npx create-react-app .
```

The following error was thrown:

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
>
> throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
>       at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
>       at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)

**Solution:**

Installing or updating `npx` with the following command:

```
npm i -g npx
```

Then running again the original command for project creation in the project's folder:

```
npx create-react-app .
```

Then it starts creating your project as expected:

> Creating a new React app in `<app-folder-path>`.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
>
> Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

Hope that helps for future searchers!