# How to find package installed globally with YARN or npm

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

How I can find out package installed globally with Yarn or npm?
(I can't remember package installed with which one!)

*let me describe more*:

I had install Vuejs with help its installation document; On that described I can use tow way to install it:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
# OR
yarn global add @vue/cli
```

and now I can remember how I instaled VueJS, with npm or yarn?! I have this problem with **JHipster** and **Quasar Framework** and **Vuetify**, after a while I forget how they had installed on my system! :-/

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking... can you be more specific? Within a project all dependencies from either tool are placed in `node_modules`

Comment: yes of course, I installed vue-cli, and now i want update it, but can't remember how i instlled vue! with npm -i -g vue-cli or yarn add global vue-cli?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages

Comment: thanks guys, But my problem is with global package installed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check your folder have `yarn.lock`(installed with `yarn`) or `package-lock.json`/`npm-shrinkwrap.json`(installed with `npm`).

For global libraries, you can check lib of `yarn`

```
yarn global list
```

to see list global libraries installed with `yarn`

and checklist global libraries installed with `npm`

```
npm list -g
```

Comment: thanks @Hongarc, I modify my question. your solution is for package installed on project;

Comment: You should check list installed with `npm` and `yarn`

Comment: I would say `npm list -g --depth 0` is a better equivalent to yarn's global list