# Where does Node.js search for modules when no node_modules folder included in project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm having trouble understanding, for example, when creating a server in Node.js - where does http module come from if there is no node_modules folder in my project?

Example bellow:

```
const http = require('http');
const onRequest = (req, res) => {
   res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
   res.write('Hello World!');
   res.end();
}
const server = http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

Thank you in advance.

P.S.

I don't have any other file in my project folder than this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

Comment: It directly ships with nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

If no node-modules then Node will search if that package is installed globally.
`npm install -g packageName`
If not installed globally then it will through error.
**But `http` package ** is **built-in module** in node.
So it is installed by default or you do not have to install it.