# ludown parse toqna command issue replaces comma with \r\n

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I am using the following command to parse lu file to json file, which then can be given to QnA Maker service to generate kb. But I found that the command replaces comma with "\r\n". For example:

````
### ? start
        ```markdown
        Lorem ipsum dolor, Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor.
        ```
````

The markdown syntax above is getting converted into the following:

```
{       
    "qnaList": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "answer": "Lorem ipsum dolor\r\n",
          "source": "custom editorial",
          "questions": [
            "start"
          ],
          "metadata": []
        },
    ]
}
```

The text is also getting truncated. How do I resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to replicate the truncating of text, even with a direct copy/paste of your code. You may need to update ludown with `npm i -g ludown`. It may also help to ensure you're using the appropriate format, using these resources:

1. [Official format guidelines](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/Ludown/docs/lu-file-format.md#external-reference)
2. [An example .lu file](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/da7b11b6fcefafc73d13b2feaca6b74ee0b5fa30/samples/javascript_nodejs/51.cafe-bot/dialogs/qna/resources/qna.lu)

There's [a PR on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/pull/925) that just got merged yesterday that addresses the `\r\n` issue.

It [hasn't been pushed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ludown) to npm yet. You might be able to pull [a nightly build](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ludown) in the next couple of days.

If you'd like to try something more immediate, you can replace the appropriate file in your installed npm package:

1. Navigate to where NPM installed ludown. On Windows 10, this is `%AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ludown\lib`. [Other OS location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)s.
2. Copy the contents from [the GitHub Repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/master/packages/Ludown/lib/parseFileContents.js) and replace the contents of `parseFileContents.js` in your npm install directory.
3. Try running the command again

You can see my successful implementation of this:

[image]