# Cannot find the web3/dist/web3.min.js when tried to install web3 using npm

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I've tried to install web3 with node.js by doing `npm install web3 --save`, but when I check the `node_modules/` folder, there's no `dist` folder and its `web3.min.js` file anywhere. Any ideas on how or why?

Comment: See if this helps -  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages). There won't be a dist folder.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need `web3.min.js` file?
The package's entry point is `src/index.js`, to use it in you project just use:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
npm install web3@0.20.6 --save
```

I hope it is works.