# nodejs cannot see installed mysql module

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install the mysql module for nodejs using npm. I'm using the windows subsystem for linux to do this. I've successfully installed using:

```
sudo npm install -g mysql
```

My console returns:

```
+ mysql@2.16.0
added 11 packages from 15 contributors in 5.779s
```

However, when importing the module using:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
```

I receive the error:

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/alesi/Documents/coding/Web/Portfolio/src/servers/server.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Other modules such as querystring and nodemailer work just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You're installing globally and not in the actually project node_modules. Need to `npm install --save mysql`. That should install to your project's node_modules and write to package.json as a dependency.

Comment: Cheers that has solved the problem. Could I ask why I can't do this globally as with other packages? Thus far I have installed other modules globally as the documentation suggests this should also work.

Comment: Ill post an answer

Answer (score 0):

When you install a package globally, the package is usually installed in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module`  on windows or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` in unix systems. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages) post.

Now in your project, when you `require()` something, it is looking to the current directory's `node_modules` folder. Because you installed the package globally, it does not exist in the project.

Running this will download the package to your *project's* `node_modules` folder, instead of *global* `node_modules`. `--save` will also write it as a dependency to `package.json`

`npm install --save mysql`

In my experience, global packages seem to be used for CLI's or running scripts from command prompt, and not for using in code.