# npm command 'serve ' not found, although it is installed

Tags: linux, npm, serve

I have installed serve with npm as "npm install serve -g" and also with yarn "yarn global add serve", but when I try to run "serve -s build" it says that "Command 'serve' not found.

Comment: it should work, can you try to uninstall and reinstall it using npm?

Comment: Still doesn't work. But I managed to install it locally (only to my project folder) with npx

Comment: okay you can may be change global installation for node_module ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages may be this can help you out

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should not install the packages globally.Try to do the following-

```
npm uninstall -g serve 
npm i -S serve
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: this didn't work for me but 
npx serve 
did

Comment: For those wondering like I did: the `-S` used to be the save option. It added the package to your dependencies. Now the `-S` has been removed. The install command adds the package by default. In case you don't want to save, use the `--no-save` option.

Answer (score 33):

I had same problem too and this helped me to fix it so try this  after installing serve;

```
 npx serve -s build
```

**or**

```
npx serve -s build -p 8000
```

(8000 = it depends by your choice)
I don't know why but this worked for me

Comment: This worked for me too

Answer (score 24):

None of these above answers worked for me, so this is what works for me :

- `sudo su`
- `npm install -g serve`

Installing as root helps globally installing `serve`

Comment: Nothing above worked for me but this one worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Make sure to have this in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`

if you're using Yarn:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$(yarn global bin)"
```

if you're using NPM:

```
export PATH="$(npm bin -g):$PATH"
```

So that the shell would know where to look for executables such as `serve`, `npx`, `live-server` etc that are installed globally.

Make sure to reload your shell config:

```
source ~/.bashrc // or ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, even for other react components I had to do the same thing (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 4):

**If anyone still gets the problem, try this:**

```
npm uninstall -g serve
npm i -S serve
yarn global add serve
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem, what I did was run the command `yarn serve -s build`
If you got it installed with npm then you can just add `npm` before the suggested command

Answer (score 0):

you can use yarn serve ./dist replace serve ./dist

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).