# Which file does npm look into when node.js global packages are being upgraded?

Tags: node.js, npm

When I ran the command to update node.js global packages using `npm update -g`, I got the following error;

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "..\..\..\Dropbox\Inv\Programming\node.js\ibkr-api" as it does not contain a package.json file.
```

However, I found out that the folder `"..\..\..\Dropbox\Inv\Programming\node.js\ibkr-api"` no longer exists.

Which file does npm look into when global packages are being upgraded? Where is it located? I believe I can fix this error if I know where this file is located and modifying it.

I am using Windows 10, node.js v11.14.

Comment: What does `npm root -g` say?

Comment: It says `C:\Users\lui\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Comment: Which npm module installed as global?

Comment: @King Stone, ibkr-api

Comment: I cannot find in https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=ibkr-api

Comment: https://github.com/pilwon/node-ib

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the first answer to this question can help you find the files you are searching

[Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

When you located your `npm\node_modules` directory you should be able to find in it the folder `"..\..\..\Dropbox\Inv\Programming\node.js\ibkr-api"`and then modify it.