# Getting "bash: typeorm: command not found" after gloablly installing typeorm on linux

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

OS:
macOS Sierra v 10.12.6

I am trying to build an application in Typescript using the typeorm and this is my first time using either.

I've used both of the following to install typeorm:

```
npm i -g typeorm
```

&

```
sudo npm i -g typeorm
```

And am seeing the following in the terminal after installing:

```
+ typeorm@0.2.21
added 127 packages from 406 contributors in 7.081s
```

But when trying to use typeorm CLI commands:

```
typeorm init --name jwt-express-typeorm --database sqlite --express
```

I keep getting this error:

```
bash: typeorm: command not found
```

I've tried uninstalling the package globally using:

```
sudo uninstall typeorm -g --save
```

and reinstalling afterward but still getting the same error. Any help would would be super appreciated!

Comment: What's your `$PATH` and is the global `node_modules` folder in there? Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages#answer-5926706

Comment: Thanks @RobertMoore! - yes node_modules are there and I am at my projects root level. Still receiving same error.

Comment: Being at the project root isn't enough. Either the **global** `node_modules` folder (not just the one for your project) must be in your `$PATH`, or you can use `npx typeorm` if you don't mind doing that instead.

Comment: No problem; turned that into an official answer now.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care to add the global `node_modules` folder (not just the project one) to your `$PATH`, you can use `npx {command-name}` instead. The global `node_modules` folder's location depends on your OS. See [Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages). One benefit of using `npx`, however, is that it works with all packages, not just globally installed ones.

Comment: Using `npx` is the best choice here.

Comment: This works...but what is npx doing differently than npm that fails?

Answer (score 0):

try appending `npm run` before `typeorm`