# pm2 where is the location of .pm2 folder

Tags: node.js, windows, pm2

A month or so followed the steps in this [blog](https://blog.cloudboost.io/nodejs-pm2-startup-on-windows-db0906328d75) and after installing pm2 generated a folder under C:\Users\.pm2 for my computer, now in a server was repeting the same steps but doesn't generate the .pm2 folder so does the default location changed or does it no longer creates this folder?

> npm install -g pm2

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages) may help you

Comment: @Japsz that post explain the generic location of the folders of the packages installed, in my case this package pm2 should create another folder called .pm2 in C:\Users\.pm2 or some other location...

Comment: Isn't the folder hidden?

Comment: by default yes but have the option in windows for folder of user to show the hidden files and folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know why but after running the command `pm2 start app.js` in my case `pm2 start "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" --name "API" -- run start-admin-scheduler` .pm2 folder appeared...