# Run Firebase Binary in Makefile

Tags: firebase, makefile, firebase-cli

I was trying to do some Makefile automation with firebase-cli. However, I found that `firebase` is not found in Makefile

```
make: firebase: No such file or directory
```

when I tried `which firebase` in terminal and it returned an empty result and hence I don't know its path. I am with MacOS and install firebase-cli with `npm install -g firebase-tools`. `firebase` command work nicely in terminal by itself. I checked according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages) to checked globally installed packages but firebase is not there.

How could I run firebase binary in a Makefile?

Comment: Run `type -a firebase` to find out what the shell is invoking when you enter `firebase`.  Based on your description my suspicion is that `firebase` could be a shell alias or function.  However I don't know anything about firebase.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that it is an alias. I would act accordingly. Thank you!