# What is "installing packages globally or locally" in react js mean?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I have started learning react js recently, when I try to setting up the environment I am confused with a word,installing packages globally and locally. What does globally and locally mean here?

Comment: How're U setting up your environment? CRA?

Comment: [You can check this out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fu95M2k21f4)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

Comment: Installing globally is making it available all over the cli on your computer.

Answer (score 6):

this concept is primarily related to the node/npm ecosystem.

The main difference between local and global packages is this:

- **local packages** are installed in the directory where you run `npm install <package-name>`, and they are put in the `node_modules` folder under this directory
- **global packages** are all put in a single place in your system (exactly where depends on your setup), regardless of where you run `npm install -g <package-name>`

In your case, you may want to install `create-react-app` package. You should install it globally in order to create a react project anywhere inside your system.

```sh
npm i -g create-react-app
```

Comment: It's not even needed to install `create-react-app` anymore since you can do `npx create-react-app my-app` and always use the latest version without polluting your system.

Answer (score 2):

Installing packages Global will make it available anywhere on your system. For example, with create-react-app, you can run that in C:\ or in C:\Users\dmesfin\ and and the command will run in both locations. To install a package globally, you will just do `npm install -g create-react-app`

Installing packages locally only allows them to be run inside you project folder. For example, if you were to do `create-react-app test-project` this would create a react project with a `package.json`. To install a package, you would simply run `npm install antd` and that package would be installed into your project and it would be visible in your `package.json`.

Generally, you want to install your generators like `create-react-app` or other CLI tools globally because they are not going to change that much and you are only going to use it once to bootstrap your project. For libraries you may use inside your project (like react or react-router), you would want to install those locally because they may change, and you may have two projects going that use two different versions.