# Globally installed node modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I just had a question. I kind of know it's silly or the answer is obvious, but I still wanna ask to get it clarified.

Do we need to set the path for globally installed node modules?

I guess, setting the path for the global node modules directory is enough.

Comment: please explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you need not set path for each installed module, you need to only set the path environment variable for the root folder of global npm directory

Taken from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926706)

> On Unix systems they are normally placed in /usr/local/lib/node or /usr/local/lib/node_modules when installed globally. If you set the NODE_PATH environment variable to this path, the modules can be found by node.
> Windows XP - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\npm\node_modules
> Windows 7, 8 and 10 - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

I hope this answers your question