# How to make test-ai-classifier plugin in combination with selenium for web automation work?

Tags: python, selenium

**Goal**:

Be able to use AI for ui elements selection in combination with selenium

**Description and results**:

The classical elements selection is so brittle and needed an alternative to that, therefore one can use the work that has been accomplished here already: https://github.com/testdotai/appium-classifier-plugin

Work has been completed for mobile using appium. Refer to this stackoverflow link [How to properly install test-ai-classifier plugin using appium for ui selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280383/how-to-properly-install-test-ai-classifier-plugin-using-appium-for-ui-selectors)

The problem that has to be solved now is to make sure or possible that one can use it with selenium for web client automation.

**What has been tried?**:

Please check the following links(only appium):
https://github.com/ericnana/appium_classifier_ai_python
[How to properly install test-ai-classifier plugin using appium for ui selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280383/how-to-properly-install-test-ai-classifier-plugin-using-appium-for-ui-selectors)

I have tried here to solve it in python.

For java I did not try. For those who are interested please check this:
https://appiumpro.com/editions/101-ai-for-appium--and-selenium

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 20.04,
python=2.7.18/3.8.5,
node = 12.14.0,
npm=6.13.4,
test-ai-classifier
selenium
pip
pytest
```

I have installed test-ai-classifier globally(npm install -g test-ai-classifier)

Erorr pointing to object detection problem

```
npm install -g test-ai-classifier
npm WARN deprecated request-promise@4.2.6: request-promise has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
/home/ecnw/.npm-global/bin/test-ai-classifier -> /home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/build-js/lib/rpc.js

> @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.7.4 install /home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
> node scripts/install.js

CPU-linux-1.7.4.tar.gz
* Downloading libtensorflow
[==============================] 1728105/bps 100% 0.0s
* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings

> canvas@2.6.1 install /home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/canvas
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
[canvas] Success: "/home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" is installed via remote

> grpc@1.24.4 install /home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
[grpc] Success: "/home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote

> test-ai-classifier@4.0.2 install /home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/test-ai-classifier/cc/main.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/test-ai-classifier/cc/detection.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/test-ai-classifier.node
  COPY Release/test-ai-classifier.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/build'

> protobufjs@6.10.2 postinstall /home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall


> test-ai-classifier@4.0.2 postinstall /home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier
> node ./postinstall.js

Will download object detection model from remote host
Checking whether /home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/model/obj_detection_model exists...
Downloading model from https://data.test.ai/appium-plugin/object-detection-model.pb...
RequestError: Error: certificate has expired
    at new RequestError (/home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (/home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (/home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Request.onRequestError (/home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
WARN: Download of object detection model failed. Object detection mode will not work.
+ test-ai-classifier@4.0.2
```

My code:

```
import unittest

#import pytest
from os import path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from testai_classifier import ClassifierClient


HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 50051
FX_DIR = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), 'fixtures')
SEL_CE = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'
import time


class TestWebAI_ClassifierDemoTest(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):

        
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=SEL_CE,
                              desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
       
       #self.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

        
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        
    
    def test_ai(self):
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(20)
        self.classifier = ClassifierClient(HOST, PORT)
        #time.sleep(20)
        
        self.driver.get("https://test.ai")
        els = self.classifier.find_elements_matching_label(self.driver, "twitter")
        els[0].click()
        assert self.classifier.current_url == "https://twitter.com/testdotai"   
        
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__== '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestWebAI_ClassifierDemoTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Error code:

```
Ran python3 webaiclassifier.py from the location where my script is located

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webaiclassifier.py", line 7, in <module>
    from testai_classifier import ClassifierClient
  File "/home/ecnw/.local/share/virtualenvs/web_test_classifier_ai-r9wXOiFG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testai_classifier/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from client import ClassifierClient
  File "/home/ecnw/.local/share/virtualenvs/web_test_classifier_ai-r9wXOiFG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testai_classifier/client.py", line 2, in <module>
    from classifier_pb2 import ElementClassificationRequest
  File "/home/ecnw/.local/share/virtualenvs/web_test_classifier_ai-r9wXOiFG/lib/python3.8/site-packages/testai_classifier/classifier_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

**What is expected?**:

Being able to use test-ai-classifier plugin in combination  with selenium for web client automation.
Clear and well explained steps used to solve this problem.

Comment: Regarding this issue the main challenge is to be able to run the classifier server.
Whenever I do from command line test-ai-classifier -h 0.0.0.0 -p 50051
I always get the following error:

Comment: I always get the following error:
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-12-18 14:00:59.767355: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3699850000 Hz

Comment: 2020-12-18 14:00:59.767750: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x3f28c80 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-12-18 14:00:59.767779: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
node: symbol lookup error: /home/ecnw/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/test-ai-classifier/build/Release/test-ai-classifier.node: undefined symbol: TF_Version

Comment: Sounds like tensorflow error of course. I have installed test-ai-classifier globally(npm install -g test-ai-classifier) by the way and then when I try running test-ai-classifier I get the above error.
The question is now which python version goes with which tensoflow version and for which test-ai-classifier version in order to be able to start the classifier server successfully.