# Please help clarifying the structure - nodejs/npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Currently I've installed Node.js and npm on my Windows 10 and first package called `hotkeys-js`. I have no idea why I have least two node_modules directories within distinct paths, i.e.:

one in

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

*which I do consider as parent working directory, correct if I am wrong?*

second which is most questionable for me:

```
C:\Users\<*whateverUsernameWouldBe*>\node_modules\first_npm
```

also the structure within first_npm as:

```
|- node_modules
|- index.js
|- package.json
|- package-lock
```

Why do I have this separate directory at all? Is it local/global? What is the purpose of this one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

Comment: @E_net4theposteditor First of all let me thank you for editing the post I've submitted. The answer to your question unfortunately is negative this time. No it does not answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `node_modules` folder under `Program Files` contains the npm modules installed as part of the nodejs installation package, and the npm modules you install with `npm install -g whatever` for common, global, use on your machine.

The `node_modules` folder in your project folder contains the npm modules you installed as part of your project.

Don't mess with the one under `Program Files` except via `npm install -g` and `npm uninstall -g` commands. At least until you get a little more proficient with  this stuff.

Your life might  be slightly easier if you create your own nodejs  / npm projects in a folder called `C:\Users\<*whateverUsernameWouldBe*>\myNodeProjects` or something like that, rather than a folder called `C:\Users\<*whateverUsernameWouldBe*>\node_modules`.  Folders named `node_modules` are generally maintained by `npm`. When you create one that isn't, you can confuse yourself. Ask me how I know this sometime.