# Cannot Uninstall two npm Packages

Tags: javascript, npm, nodes

I have installed node-gyp in order to install scrypt. While installing the node-gyp package the following two packages were installed along with it:

> 101@1.6.3

> d@1.0.1

I have tried to remove these two packages, realising that I did not need the node-gyp and scrypt packages, but `sudo npm uninstall` does not remove them. How can I uninstall these packages?

Comment: Why do you want to install these packages? Are they dependencies of node-gyp? What does the package-lock.json indicate they are dependencies of?

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderStaroselsky I have not explicitly installed them, but they were installed with node-gyp. I have since removed node-gyp (and thus cannot verify the dependencies), but wasn't able to remove these two packages.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts with repetitive taglines like "Thank You, J". Your posts are all "signed" by your usercard already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `package.json` file contains entries for these modules (101@1.6.3 and d@1.0.1), delete those lines.

Then delete your `package-lock.json` file.

Then delete your `node_modules` folder.

Now run `npm install`

Comment: Thank you @Bishan. Actually, since the node-gyp site (https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrypt) suggested to install this package (which has installed the two packages that I am trying to remove) globally, these two packages were installed globally as well. I can delete the folders in my node_modules, but it is strange that the npm uninstall command is not working. I would have liked to remove them properly from my system.

Comment: @JF0001 Read [Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages) and follow above steps to remove Global libraries

Answer (score 1):

Its Depends on how you have installed those packages.

if it's a local package to the project

use "**npm uninstall --save 'package name**'"
or simply remove the package from package.json of your project. Then Delete node_modules folder and install npm again using "npm install"

if it's a global package
use **[sudo] npm uninstall -g "package name"**

use **sudo** based on which OS your are using .

Comment: Incorrect. Use sudo only if NPM is installed in /usr on Linux. Users using [n] with a custom prefix do not need to.