# How to uninstall mutiple packages from package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I have some dependencies from Aws cdk 1 in this form

```
"@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2": "^1.126.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-authorizers": "^1.126.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-integrations": "^1.126.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-budgets": "^1.126.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-certificatemanager": "^1.126.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront": "^1.126.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch": "^1.126.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch-actions": "^1.126.0",
    "@aws-cdk/aws-cognito": "^1.126.0",
    ....
```

I want to uninstall these packages in one shot, as per my understanding they have pattern @aws-cdk/* is it possible but there is not luck, is there a way to remove multiple packages in one shot when they have a pattern?

Comment: Just delete them from the file and run `npm install`

Comment: delete them in the package.json, delete packagelock.json as well then `npm install`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Uninstall two npm Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978786/cannot-uninstall-two-npm-packages)