# where does npx saves packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I found out that when I do at the first time npx [package] it prompts me to install the package: "Need to install the following packages"

And if I run the command again it doesn't ask it again,
I'm curious where does it save this package on my computer?

Important to mention: I don't have the package on a local/node_modules folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does npm install packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages)

Comment: No, because I don't see there any of the packages I used with npx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere in `~/.npm/_npx`.

asdf

Comment: Windows equivalent is probably %LocalAppData%\npm-cache\