# creation of signalr.js file, when installing through npm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0) documentation for setting up the clientside of a project using signalr.
So I have a asp.net core mvc project, and I start by running these commands in the nuget package manager command line:

```
npm init -y
npm install @microsoft/signalr
```

After doing this, the documentation has this text:

```
npm installs the package contents in the node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\browser folder. 
Create a new folder named signalr under the wwwroot\lib folder. Copy the signalr.js file to the 
wwwroot\lib\signalr folder.
```

This part is super confusing to me. I don't know where `node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\browser` directory is, I cannot find anything called node_modules. Then it also says that I should Copy the `signalr.js file`, that's also confusing. I have no such file anywhere in the project, I don't know where to copy from.

After this, the documentation says another thing which is pretty confusing:

```
Reference the SignalR JavaScript client in the <script> element. For example:
     <script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
```

This does'nt make to much sense to me. Where should I put this tag? In all view files in my project? perhaps in a word file on my local pc?

I really hope someone can help clearing these things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know where node_modules@microsoft\signalr\dist\browser directory is, I cannot find anything called node_modules.

You can run `npm list -g` to see which **global** libraries are installed and where they're located.

You can run `npm list` to see the installed **non-global** libraries for your current location.

[image]

I suppose you use **Windows system**. If you install signalr package **globally**, you will find the installed folder in: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.

If you install **non-global library**, you will find the installed folder in your **solution folder** (**not** project folder).

For example, I create the solution in `D:\repos\MvcProjct`, the `node_modules\@microsoft\signalr\dist\browser` will exist in it(`D:\repos\MvcProjct\node_modules\...`).

More details you could refer to the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926706/11398810

> This does'nt make to much sense to me. Where should I put this tag? In all view files in my project? perhaps in a word file on my local pc?

It depends on you. If you want to globally use this js file, you could put it in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Dotnetcore5</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        //...
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()

        </main>
    </div>    
    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        //..
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
 //add here....
    <script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
    
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

If you only want to use in specific view, you just put it in the specific view:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
}
```