# Vue CLI: What exactly happens when I use "npm install"?

Tags: npm, anaconda, npm-install

I've been using the command line for some time now, but I'm still not sure what exactly happens when I do certain things - and I'm not sure what to google for help.

When I'm working with Anaconda and Python, I found the environments I created in `C:\Users\<User>\Anaconda3\envs`. And every python package I install in an environment seems to go there. Great!

But how does this work outside of Anaconda/Python? For example, I installed the vue CLI via `npm install -g @vue/cli`. What exactly happens when I do this; or more precicely, where are files saved?

During the creation of a new vue project, a readme.md is created as well. It states that users should simply `npm install` to setup the project. It seems that this command installs all packages stated in the `package.json`. I would like to try out if this command works for new users, but I already (obviously) have everything installed. Can I create some kind of environment (like I do with Anaconda for Python) to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: npm will install vue-cli in global path, how can i find it.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926706/15859431)

Comment: second question,do you wish to use an existing files to install package.json?

Comment: It would be best if I could create like a new and separated environment with nothing installed to try the installation

Comment: if you didn't install anything in global, you will get separated environment, so it take so big size in node_modules (pnpm is to solve this problem)