# I get an error installing create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tar

I can't install react app normaly.The src and public folder is missing. I'm using **node v18.13.0** and **npm v9.4.0 **

[image: 1]

I did this command **npx create-react-app my-site**.And I expecting all dependencies to be installed but I got an error message

Answer (score 1):

### Installation

To start a new Create React App project with TypeScript, you can run:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

or

```
yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript
```

> If you've previously installed create-react-app globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, we recommend you uninstall the package
> using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that `npx` always uses the `latest version`.
>
> Global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

### Troubleshooting

If your project is not created with TypeScript enabled, npx may be using a cached version of create-react-app. Remove previously installed versions with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` (see [#6119](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6119#issuecomment-451614035)).

If you are currently using [create-react-app-typescript](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/), see [this blog post](https://vincenttunru.com/migrate-create-react-app-typescript-to-create-react-app/) for instructions on how to migrate to Create React App.

Constant enums and namespaces are not supported, you can learn about the constraints of [using Babel with TypeScript here.](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript#caveats)

See [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) for full details: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

Comment: thanks for your answer but i tried to install locally and i still got the same error. Could you please tell me if my version of node could be causing a problem? I installed Node.js v18.13.0. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When the system has a globally installed CRA (create-react-app) and we try to create a new app with `npx` it fails due to the conflict. In order to fix this, we need to remove the global installation and then use `npx` to install a new app.

We can uninstall with:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

and then clear the `npx` cache

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

There is an error with the command to create react app, the following is the correct one:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i tried to install locally and i still got the same error. Could you please tell me if my version of node could be causing a problem? I installed Node.js v18.13.0. Thanks in advance

Comment: how did you install node and the global package? The above should work for Node v18. Depending on your node installation method, we should investigate into where the directory for global installation is? 


For `Yarn`: the directory is:

Mac:`~/.config/yarn/global`
Linux: `/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global`
Windows: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global`

Comment: I installed node from node.org by downloading the recommended version for my system which is node v18.14.0

Comment: Did you check for the global installation? For yarn, the above were the directories. For npm, check Rohit's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926706/10162015)

If you find CRA there, please delete it.